# Div is not right justified

Tags: html, css

I want the text of the second and third divs to be on the right. I tried that by using `margin-left: auto` and setting all divs to `display: inline-block`. It didn't work with `float: left` either. What have I done wrong?

It should look like this

[image]

```css
.header > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right-justified{
  margin-left: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
      <div>
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Left</div>
      </div>
        <div class="right-justified">
          <div>Right</div>
          <div>Right</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>Right</div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use flexbox or grid for better layout design to become a great developer rather than using this silly techniques.

**try out the code Below--**

```css
.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
.right-justified{
    display: flex;

}
.mid{
    align-self: center;
    margin:0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>template</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <div>
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Left</div>
      </div>
      <div  class="right-justified">
        <div>
          <div>Right</div>
          <div>Right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mid">
          <div>Right</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @software don't forget to add your stylesheet properly.

Comment: I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `flex` on the `.header` and `margin-left: auto` on the `.right-justified`

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
}

.right-justified {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div>
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-justified">
    <div>Right</div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, give your HTML structure specific class names and the just float the items as you desire. You can, furthermore, align the text inside the columns as you wish.

```
<section class="header">
  <div class="header-col-left">
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-col-right">
    <div>
      <div>col 1 right</div>
      <div>col 1 right</div>
    </div>
    <div>col 2 right</div>
  </div>
</section>

.header-col-left {
  float: left;
}
.header-col-right {
  float :right;
}
.header-col-right > div {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use display: flex and align-items:center to get the vertical alignment you are looking for.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.right-justified {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div>
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-justified">
    <div>Right</div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </div>
</section>
```